# Confused about subset example

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

> Theorem: Let $f: X \to Y$ be a function. Then, for all subsets $A, B$ of $X, \  f(A \cap B) \subseteq f(A) \cap f(B)$.

> ...

> What if $f$ is not one-one? The above observation gives you a hint to produce an example where the inclusion is proper. If $f$ is not one-one, there exist $x_1, x_2 \in X, x_1 \ne x_2$ such that $f(x_1) = f(x_2) = y \in Y$. Choose $A = \{x_1\}, B = \{x_2\}$. Then, $A \cap B = \emptyset$, and so $\color{red}{f(A \cap B) = \emptyset \not \subseteq \{y\} = f(A) \cap f(B)}$.

My question is about the $\color{red}{\text{part in red}}$ above. I think it's incorrect for two reasons: (1) it contradicts the theorem above and (2) $\emptyset \subseteq \{y\}.$ Is it possible that the authors meant to conclude $f(A) \cap f(B) = \{y\} \not \subseteq \emptyset = f(A \cap B)$? Just making sure I follow my book.

[Snapshot from my book](https://ibb.co/jw7mRmg)

Comment: It is a typo; they meant $\subsetneq$

Comment: The symbol they are using is $\subsetneq$, not $\not\subseteq$.

Comment: I have always seen the symbol written $\subsetneq$. In this book, the slash goes through both of the bottom lines, which is somewhat odd, but just a notation choice. The author probably interprets $\subseteq$ as a $\subset$ and an $=$ sign which overlap. So the bottom of the author's symbol looks like $\neq$.

Comment: Compare ``\subsetneq`` $\Large \subsetneq$ with ``\varsubsetneq`` $\Large \varsubsetneq$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it means that $f(A \cap B) = \emptyset \subset \{y\} $ but the sets are different
(an example where the inclusion is proper).

Answer (score 1):

The example they gave is standard and it is not wrong, rather your notation is off. What they mean is that when $f$ is not injective, then it is not always true that $f(A \cap B) = f(A) \cap f(B)$ for all subsets $A, B \subseteq X$ (they prove one inclusion, while the other is not hard to prove exactly the way the authors were proposing in the case that $f$ is actually injective).